# Conditional "using", "provides", etc within module-info.java? JVM command line?

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-module

One of the unit tests I'd like to create is to use `ServiceLoader` to load up the service that is under test, locally, within that module.

```
module {
  ...
  provides foo.bar.Baz with foo.bar.Bazoikle;
  uses foo.bar.Baz; // yuck!
  ...
}
```

Having that `uses` in there next to the `provides` just seems weird/yucky/wrong.  But that's precisely what I need for that local module test, which will tell me if I've exposed the service properly.  An essentially identical test from within our integration suite will show that it can be imported properly, exposing potential configuration errors.  When the local exposure passes and the integration fails, it says to me "Time to update your build.gradle again", which serves to demonstrate how it should be done by others.

So other than moving my tests to some other module/project (which is a case already handled by my integration test), is there anything I can do to avoid shipping a module that `uses` the service that at also `provides`?

EDIT:
The JVM has several command line options for various module changes, suitable for test environments, `add-module`, `patch-module`, etcetera.  However, there doesn't seem to be any similar settings for *services* provided or consumed by said modules.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Or am I making a big deal about the whole "uses & provides" thing?

Comment: You are correct that this module declaration is wrong. But it is not clear to me why you think you need it. The "essentially identical test" which is external to the module should be the only one you need. The "unit test" (hint: it's not) sounds unnecessary.

Comment: We could quibble over the definition of a unit test, but meh.  This test, regardless of its category, is a useful one.  Successful export != successful import.  And while succeeding at importing a module also proves it was exported properly, failing to import a module doesn't tell you where the problem lies.  This "unnecessary" test does.  As someone new to modules, I find the distinction valuable.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that a test to see whether something was exported needs to or should exist within the module itself. You can only test that properly from outside the module. Anyway, to answer your original question: no, there is no way to have a condition `uses`.